# Are Questions on Yoga and Pranayam On-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Since Hinduism is such vast and full of rich and diverse subject, as a community we need to agree on few on-topics/off-topics hints I guess.

According to Hinduism.SE [Help centre](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) below are on-topic Questions here:

- Hindu scripture and mythology.
- Academic questions about Hindu philosophical thought.
- Questions about Hindu practices.
- Historical questions about the evolution of Hinduism.
- Different sects of Hinduism and their beliefs.

Sure, **there is no mention of Yoga/Pranayam directly here**, and I understand that not everything can be documented to be on-topic in one place. Agree!!

But consider this:

If someone ask question on Hinduism.SE about a specific Pranayam, say, Mann Kumbhak, Rechak and Purak pranayams, and asks more details about the pranayam itself, like how to do it, what benefits etc.

Shall we treat it as on-topic, just because that Pranayam was mentioned in Hindu Scriptures?

Comment: Yes, questions about Patanjali Yoga, Pranayama, etc. are absolutely on-topic here.  That would fall under Hindu practices.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Since you happened to be 1 of the moderators on this site, you may want to post your comment as answer so that all community members will know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, questions about Patanjali Yoga, Pranayama, etc. are absolutely on-topic here.  That would fall under Hindu practices.

Just keep in mind that personal advice questions are not allowed here, so questions like "My breathing is getting shallow when I try to do Pranayamam for extended periods of time, what am I doing wrong?" wouldn't be allowed.  And scientific speculation isn't allowed, so a question like "What are the cardiovascular benefits of Pranayamam according to modern science?" wouldn't be allowed either.  But questions like "What is the procedure for Rechak Pranayama according to Hindu scripture?" or "Is Iyengar Yoga based on the Sri Vaishnava tradition?" (which I [asked already](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7562/36)) are absolutely fine.